# SQL Power Shell with Server 8... Cannot enable TCP/IP protocol

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

Created a new Server 8 machine. Testing out a .net + SQL Server 2012 site. I am trying to remotely connect to the machine but in order to do so I need to enable TCP/IP protocol. If I try and do it visually through the Computer Management Console I get some strange behavior in that if I try to select any Yes/No dropdown list it simply gives me a blank list and I cannot change the value. I can enable the TCP/IP as a whole by selecting it from the context menu in the config, but when I go into the properties I get enabled = No for all IP1, IP2, etc... areas.

I then tried to change it using SQLPS... but does not seem to take... the strange thing is that I notice that under properties there is nothing... take a look and let me know..

```
PS SQLSERVER> $MachineObject.getsmoobject($tcp.urn.Value + "/IPAddress[@Name='IP2']")



Parent              : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServerProtocol
IPAddressProperties : {Active, Enabled, IpAddress, TcpDynamicPorts...}
IPAddress           : 192.168.0.24
Urn                 : ManagedComputer[@Name='WIN-LLJKBQ6OVVR']/ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name
                      ='Tcp']/IPAddress[@Name='IP2']
Name                : IP2
Properties          : {}
UserData            :
State               : Existing
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enable TCP/IP protocol on SQL Server, not only do you enable port 1433 (or whatever) but you also need to make sure you bound the listener to the right interface.  In the past, SQL server would bind to 0.0.0.0  but in recent versions you can bind to one of the many options :  127.1, 192.168.1.xx, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, ::1 , etc.

Please run "SQL Server COnfiguration Manager" , look in the network configuration, and make sure you configured the listener bindings correctly.  You can verify it using "netstat -an" in a shell.

Also, double check that your user account is actually enabled and that SQL Server "mixed auth" is probably enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the exercise. Bindings were there, but for some reason per my question I am not able to change any drop down boxes that are Yes/No.. Either a bad install or something wonky with Server 8 Beta / SQL Server 2012. In the end turning it on via powershell and rebooting the machine worked even though the Config Manager says indicates otherwise. Thanks.